# Dapper.contrib Insert - Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Tags: npgsql, dapper-contrib

Using:
`.NET Core 1.1`
`Dapper.Contrib`
`Npgsql`

On Postgresql 9.6

I am trying to use `.InsertAsync` extension method but getting error:
`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
   at PostgresAdapter.<InsertAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

If I use normal `.Insert` method, everything works OK.
What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/689

Which, looking at the issue tracker, is fixed but unreleased.

You could try building from the latest source, or applying just that particular fix yourself.

Comment: Thanks, how can I tell from githubs `release` tab which commits / pull requests are released and which are not?

Comment: I just looked at the date of the last release and the date of the ticket, plus comments about v2.